# How to disable hover on QTreeWidget during mouseMove()?

Tags: qt, widget, qt5

I have created my own custom QTreeWidget, and overrided the mouseMoveEvent.
It looks something like the below,

```
MyTreeWidget::mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent* aEvent)
{
QTreeWidget::mouseMoveEvent(aEvent); // This line causes the issue

// My logic
}
```

I'm getting a hovering effect on the treewidget, when mouseMove happens (This is not expected). I have also set the focus (Qt::WA_MacShowFocusRect) to be false. But still, see the hover effect when I move the mouse in and out. I found out this is because of the line - QTreeWidget::mouseMoveEvent(aEvent), which calls the base class implementation which sets the hover. But, I need that to be called to support reorder of tree items, when mouseTracking is enabled.

I don't find any way to unset the hover events. Any help around this?

Comment: What happens if you call the base method after your logic? Or if you don't call it at all (only your logic)?

Comment: The issue is still seen when I call the base method after my logic. If I don't call it, then drag and drop doesn't work.

Comment: I think you can use style sheets to customize the background color (to transparent) when the mouse is over an item. See https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-examples.html#customizing-qtreeview

Comment: Fabio - Thanks that helped ! It works.